# Python turn list values into String

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I've got the list values stored as:

```
country = [u'USA']
```

How can I turn it into just 'USA'. I've tried `str(country)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: "Get the first element of the list"? `[u'USA']` is a *list* that contains a [unicode] string as the first and only element. The `__str__` protocol for a list will output the "[..]" as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apply `str()` on the element not on the list:

```
In [206]: country = [u'USA']

In [207]: country[0] = str(country[0])

In [208]: country
Out[208]: ['USA']
```

or may be you meant this:

```
In [217]: country = [u'USA']

In [218]: country = str(country[0])

In [219]: country
Out[219]: 'USA'
```

Comment: Thanks...it was the second version. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

`country` is a list that already contains Unicode strings. You don't need to convert it. The `u''` syntax is just the item representation as a Python literal (how you would type it in a Python source code).

If you do need a bytestring; use `.encode()` method with an appropriate character encoding e.g.:

```
b = country[0].encode("ascii")
```

In general, structure a text processing code as [Unicode sandwich](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html) i.e., use Unicode internally and use bytes only to communicate with outside world; don't mix the two.